# How to replace char two times in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string `"%hello%"` and i want to get output `"{hello}"`.
I tried all my ideas but not working or not compiling.
I added now compile error, i know the problem is in array index.
It's my code:

```cs
char[] charArr = vars.xyz.ToCharArray();
StringBuilder asda = new StringBuilder(vars.xyz);
foreach (char ch in charArr)
{
    vars.count++;
    vars.charArrayCounter++;
    if (ch.Equals('%'))
    {
        vars.charCounter++;
    }
    switch (vars.charCounter)
    {
        case 1:
            asda[vars.charArrayCounter - 1] = '{';
            break;
        case 2:
            asda[vars.charArrayCounter - 1] = '{';
            vars.charCounter = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

I get compile error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: „Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

In line: `asda[vars.charArrayCounter - 1] = '{';`

Comment: What did you try? Show us some code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RWy4Tdfw

Comment: Please [edit] that code into your question, include the complete text of compile error  (as text, not as an image) and include the output you now get and why that isn't correct.

Comment: What do you know about the string? What are the constraints? Are you guaranteed to have a matching end point? What about `"{he{llo}"`?

Comment: I can't edit my post to add the compile error and the line where it has problem

Comment: I added a compile error and something error's. The problem is in a array index. In asda variable i can't change a index to '}'

When i remove StringBuilder to simple char array it gives `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: „Index was outside the bounds of the array.”`

Comment: What is the value of that charArrayCounter and what is the length of that asda?

Comment: Ok i know the problem, i don't see it. Value of charArrayCounter is 47, asda is 17 length.

Comment: What is that vars thing anyway? Are you keeping global state there?

Comment: Yes it has global variables, i created it to debug easier

Comment: That also introduce a wide variety of bugs and pitfalls ....

Comment: I don't use this in final code.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sK8QL4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your juggling with indexes is error prone, specially if you have those as global state.

If I keep close to what you have now I suggest building up the StringBuilder by appending a char one by one and keep state to know if you encounteres a `%` character so you know what you need to append instead. That solves the Index out of range exeception by simply omitting index operations from the loop.

If I assume your `vars` is simlar to this:

```
static class vars
{
  public static string xyz ="%hello%"; 
}
```

That code could look like this:

```
char[] charArr = vars.xyz.ToCharArray();
StringBuilder asda = new StringBuilder();
var state = 0; // counter for 1st or 2nd replace
foreach (char ch in charArr)
{
    if (ch.Equals('%'))
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case 0: // first
                asda.Append('{');     
            break;
            case 1: //second
                asda.Append('}');     
            break;
            default:
                // error? because we have now found 3 % chars
            break;
        }
        state++; // counter goes up
    } else {
      asda.Append(ch);  // add to the stringbuilder
    }
}
```

and that outputs {hello} in my testing. It will produce for %hel%lo% the result {hel}lo% but you can know something was off because state will be > 1.

The much shorter alternative (which opens new error cases) but omits any loops, leverages the IndexOf and LastIndexOf methods of the String class

```
StringBuilder asda2 = new StringBuilder(vars.xyz);
asda2[vars.xyz.IndexOf('%')]='{';
asda2[vars.xyz.LastIndexOf('%')]='}';
```

This has the benfit it will for the input %hel%lo% the result {hel%lo} which is maybe preferble. Do check if the input as a % at all, or it fail. I leave that for others to solve.

Answer (score 3):

```
var asda = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(vars.xyz, @"%([^%]+)%", "{$1}");
```